# ember.containerview defined like regular view?

Tags: ember.js

can you define a containerview like this and have it work as a regular view? because it is not working for me. but when i switch to just a regular Ember.View.extend(), the title and description renders.

App.SectionView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        classNames: ['section'],
        defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile(sectionTemplate),
        titleBinding: 'content.title',
        descriptionBinding: 'content.description'
    });

does containerView not work with template?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContainerView overrides #render, so it doesn't work with templates. So, what you should do is have App.SectionView be an Ember.View, display your title and description there, and have the ContainerView be a subview.

Comment: i actually did it the other way around and have the sectionview as a childview of my containerview. thanks!

Comment: How `ContainerView ` can be a subview for `Ember.View`?